# New Character in Vikings

Tags: character, vikings

On the season finale of Vikings this new character is introduced:

[image]

And so far Vikings has been as accurate as a series can be about an actual historical time and still be a show. But I'm afraid that the Tale of Ragnar's sons has ended, and so, who is this new character? He appears to be an English monk, but he has a sword of a Viking, as shown when he's having sex with that lady and the end of the episode. Who is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this actor is **Jonathan Rhys-Meyers** who is playing a medieval bishop named **Heahmund**.

From [this interview with Hirst](http://ew.com/tv/2017/01/26/vikings-jonathan-rhys-meyers-bishop-season-5/)

> "He's a man of Wessex, and he's gonna come in as a worthy opponent to Ivar," Hirst promises, comparing the character to Richard III. "His whole life is about deeply passionate commitments. He's a wild card who happens to be [played by] Jonathan Rhys Meyers, who is himself kind of a wild card!"

From [Travelers Today](http://www.travelerstoday.com/articles/36705/20170128/vikings-introduce-jonathan-rhys-meyers-new-character-role-season-4.htm)

> The creator also added that Rhys-Meyers' character as Headmund will probably be against Ivar and it seems like however, their encounter will not happen yet in the next season; however, his character will appear in the episode of season four, Ace Showbiz reported. The film creator added that he is really perfect for this crazy and religious kind of character.

Comment: I see. Well, the actor is indeed a worthy choise to the role. But still, he's a monk? How come he has the power and the ability to go to war against Ivar? Is he more than just a religious person, maybe a Earl (the English equivalent to Jarl), or even yet a king? And what about the sword? Has any of this been revelead yet or will we have to wait until next season?

Comment: Wait for the next season I suppose. This character is introduced in finale.

Comment: If he is Bishop Heahmund then it is a portrayal of a real historical figure who fought and died in the Battle of Marton. He was the not only early Medieval bishop to fight in battle it was quite common for example Bishop Odo who was the brother  of William the Conqueror fought at the Battle of Hastings. He is depicted on the Bayeux Tapestry wielding a mace as it was said he did not want to spill a mans blood.